# AForge.portable how to detect a piece of paper in an image

Tags: android, xamarin.android, aforge

I am using AForge.portable on an Android tablet to create a way to convert a picture of a piece of paper into what might pass as a scanned image.  My code is as follows:

```
    public static Bitmap ConvertToScan(Bitmap img)
    {
        BlobCounterBase bc = new BlobCounter();
        bc.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Area;

        var bm = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)img).Clone(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        var grayImage = filter.Apply(bm);

        SobelEdgeDetector sobelfilter = new SobelEdgeDetector();
        sobelfilter.ApplyInPlace(grayImage);

        bc.ProcessImage(grayImage);

        Blob[] blobs = bc.GetObjectsInformation();

        //I Assume the first/largest blob is what I want.  
        List<IntPoint> edgePoints = bc.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[0]);
        List<IntPoint> corners = PointsCloud.FindQuadrilateralCorners(edgePoints);

        QuadrilateralTransformation qfilter = new QuadrilateralTransformation(corners, img.Width, img.Height);
        Bitmap newImage = (Bitmap)qfilter.Apply((System.Drawing.Bitmap)img);

        return newImage;
    }
```

If I display grayImage after it has gone through the SobelEdgeDetector, I get a nice highlight of the boundary of the piece of paper.  I was thinking that passing this image through the BlobCounter would give me the edgePoints of the largest blob, which should be the paper.  What happens is that it only comes up with one blob being the entire image.  I suspect that since the paper is just an outline and not a solid, the BlobCounter is not selecting it.  Does anyone know how use Aforge to detect the corners of the largest object outline in an image?